# TS Jest not distinguishing custom error class from the standard javascript error class

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using TS Jest and and i am trying to test if a function throws a custom error i created called InvalidOperatorError.

It is imported from a different file using ES6 imports, and its being detected as an Error instead of an InvalidOperatorError.

The test result error message logged in the console:

```
expect(received).toThrow(expected)

Expected constructor: InvalidOperatorError
Received constructor: Error

Received message: "Invalid operator!"
```

My test is written as this:

```
it('throws InvalidOperatorError when the operator passed is \"NONE\"', () => {
    expect(() => {calculate(0, 0, Operator.NONE)}).toThrow(InvalidOperatorError)
})
```

My custom error class (imported from a separate file):

```
export class InvalidOperatorError extends Error {
    constructor(message: string | undefined){
        super(message)
        this.name = "InvalidOperatorError"
    }
}
```

The calculate function:

```
export const calculate = (n1: number, n2: number, op: Operator): number => {
    switch(op){
        case SUM: return n1 + n2
        case SUB: return n1 - n2
        case MULT: return n1 * n2
        case DIV: return n1 / n2
        default: throw new InvalidOperatorError("Invalid operator!")
    }
}
```

The enum:

```
export enum Operator {
    NONE,
    SUM,
    SUB,
    MULT,
    DIV
}
```

Comment: Note: This problem only occurs with custom error classes.

Comment: Could you also share the implementation of calculate function?

Comment: Added it and the enum to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out that my issue was in the tsconfig file, where, in the compiler options, target was set to ES5 instead of ES6. The code works correctly, the problem was in the configuration of TS.